# Marquee doesn't work properly with settimeout on all computer systems

Tags: javascript, vb.net, asp-classic

I am using marquee to scroll news on my page and also using settimeout to fade In/Out message on the same page.
Marquee scroll news stops for a second and then continues when other message fade In/Out on the same page.
I think this behaviour accours becuase of settimeout function in javascript.
**Note: It doesn't happend on all pcs, i have tested this page on new machines and it is working fine.**
I don't know the real root cause of the problem.

Page work fine on firefox on the same machine which is causing problem (IE)

Comment: Any specifics on which browsers are being used?

Comment: Using IE 7/8 and Firefox - This is not easy to replicate this issue.

Comment: demo code is posted on following link http://forums.asp.net/p/1778822/4875058.aspx/1?Re+Maqruee+doesn+t+work+properly+with+settimeout+on+all+Pc+s

Comment: just a quick note on the code - scrolldelay=150, notice the attribute value is not in quotes. I know this is petty, but can cause problems in some browsers. Just something noticed at first glance.

Comment: Thanks. I have put the value in double quotes but still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED this issue by using jquery and fade IN/OUT.